# Import ReactiveCocoa, or PromiseKit, or BrightFutures as sources?

Tags: xcode, plugins, reactive-cocoa, dispatch, dispatch-async

I have an OSX project (xcode plugin) and I want to use the `ReactiveCocoa` paradigms in it (`PromiseKit and`BrightFutures` are the other implementations of the same paradigms so I need to import at least one from these 3 frameworks/libraries).

The problem is it seems impossible to import them as compiled frameworks into my project because it is **plugin**. In my project I used `dispatch_async` and `dispatch_after` functions only but their nested blocks look awful.

The only solution I found is import one from these frameworks as sources but I don't know how to detach their code. So could anybody help with this trouble? Or maybe are there any other similar libraries which are already represented as source files only?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
Use a dependency manager like **Cocoapods** or **Carthage**.

---

**Longer Answer:** You can do it manually, but even if you don't want to use any of those, you can look at the *.podspec* file and see how it's supposed to be used. For example [BrightFutures.podspec](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures/blob/master/BrightFutures.podspec) says:

> s.source_files = 'BrightFutures/*.swift'
>
> s.dependency 'Result', '0.6.0-beta.6'

That means that you need to import all the *.swift* files inside the [BrightFutures folder](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures/tree/master/BrightFutures), and that it won't work unless you also import the files from another project called [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result).

But please, just let the tools do that for you. You'll be happier. :)